TextField crash when use 'TextFields.bindAutoCompletion()'
--module-path /media/alumne/ssd_clase/PRO/JavaJDK/javafx-sdk-21.0.2/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED 

I have this path in the vm arguments when i try to execute the program usuing controlsFX i get this error:
Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)  at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1082) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method   at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)     at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/controlsfx/control/textfield/TextFields   at controlador.AemetController.initialize(AemetController.java:53)  at javafx.fxml@21.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2670)     at javafx.fxml@21.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)     at javafx.fxml@21.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3376)     at javafx.fxml@21.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3332)     at javafx.fxml@21.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3300)     at javafx.fxml@21.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3272)     at javafx.fxml@21.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3248)     at javafx.fxml@21.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3241)     at aplicacion.Main.start(Main.java:16)  at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)   at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)     at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)     at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)  at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)   at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$10(GtkApplication.java:263)    ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)  ... 19 more Exception running application aplicacion.Main

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields -- The solution is to put ControlsFX on the module-path/class-path.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I wouldn't call an exception like that a crash.  A crash with a Java system is usually pretty rare, and can occur when the java virtual machine or a native library used by an application experiences a fatal failure (e.g. the system runs out of memory in an unhandled way) causing the JVM to immediately exit.  That isn't what is happening here.

Instead, you have a standard Java exception due to an inaccessible class.  You can see Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?.  Be aware though, if your application is modular there may be additional access restrictions on classes that are not referred to in some of the answers to that related question.

For ControlsFX in particular there is a guide you should be aware of: Using ControlsFX with JDK 9 and above -> for instance for autocompletion binding which you appear to be using from your question title, you need: --add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls.  Though there may be other issues in your code as well that cause you to have errors.
